# Estimating quantiles from a sample(R-9)

Tags: descriptive-statistics, quantiles, qq-plot

The Wikipedia page of [quantile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile) shows 9 types of quantile estimators.

Here is the last type R-9:

Let $h$ be the index of a sample size $N$ and $x_h$ be the quantile estimate, then

$$Q_p = x_{⌊h⌋} + (h − ⌊h⌋) (x_{⌊h⌋ + 1} − x_{⌊h⌋})$$
$$where\ h=(N + 1/4)p + 3/8$$

> The resulting quantile estimates are approximately unbiased for the expected order statistics if x is normally distributed.

But how to prove that the quantile estimates are approximately unbiased if x is normally distributed?

Answer (score 0):

Not a full answer, but at least a pointer to literature: the Wikipedia page refers to [Hyndman & Fan (1996, *The American Statistician*)](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2684934?origin=JSTOR-pdf), which collects different types of quantiles. For Type 9 specifically, Hyndman & Fan (1996) say that Blom (*Statistical Estimates and Transformed Beta-Variables*, Wiley, 1958) show this approximate unbiasedness.